# EnumDesktopWindows doesn't find Windows10 search window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to find Windows 10 search window (called by Win + S shortkey) using [EnumDesktopWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopwindows), but it seems that this windows isn't passed to the callback function.
With inspect (from Windows Kit) utility I found that class name of the search window is `SearchPane`, but I didn't find this name as a result of my test program:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyCallback(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t strText[256];

    GetClassName(hwnd, strText, 256);

    wcout << strText << endl;

    if (wcscmp(strText, L"SearchPane") == 0)
    {
        wcout << L"***** DONE *****" << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    Sleep(6000);
    ::EnumDesktopWindows(nullptr, MyCallback, NULL);
}
```

`Sleep(6000)` is needed for me to open search window.
As a result I don't see "***** DONE *****" text or even some class name that is similar to `SearchPane`.

The main purpose is to find if search window overlaps my app window, but for now I even can't detect if search window is opened and its position.

Comment: Did you try using `FindWindow` instead?

Comment: think you need have `<disableWindowFiltering>true</disableWindowFiltering>` in manifest - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests

Comment: No, In general I need to find any window that overlaps my app window, so EnumDesktopWindows is excellent function for this. But I found that it doesn't work for search window on Windows 10. After some investigations I found out that this window isn't passed to MyCallback.

Comment: because by default windows filter such windows. for enumerate immersive windows from the desktop you need set in manifest `<disableWindowFiltering>true</disableWindowFiltering>`

Comment: @RbMm, I've never worked with application manifests. How should I add the parameter here? Should I create new manifest file or is it possible to set manifest options in project settings in Visual Studio?

Comment: It's probably not a top-level window and is instead a child window of Explorer.  Use Spyxx (compes with MSVS) to check this.

Comment: @RbMm, I created following manifest (https://pastebin.com/wtNmD4e7) and set it as a additional manifest file for my project. But still can't find needed window.

Comment: @RichardCritten, search windows is closed after it had lost focus, so I can't catch it with spy++

Comment: Why do you need to know if something is overlapping your window?

Comment: @RichardCritten, I found this window in spy++ by hwnd and this window has no parents.

Comment: You don't need to enumerate windows at all. Just use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/winevents-collision169), and have the system tell you, when windows are created and destroyed.

Comment: Classical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You ask about your attempted solution instead of the actual problem you want to solve.